# Symfony2 AJAX problems, response returns not refreshed data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony, response

I'm working with Symfony2 and AJAX and have some problems, my controller returns old data from database. I tried var_dump variable before returning and everything was fine, but JsonResponse returns old data.
My controller:

public function returnOrderAction(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->request->get('id');

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $bookEntity = $em->getRepository('BooksBundle:Book')->find($id);
    $user = $this->getUser()->getId();
    $this->get('order.complete')->returnOrder($bookEntity, $user);
    $quantity = $bookEntity->getQuantity();

    if (!$bookEntity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Book entity.');
    }

    return new JsonResponse(array(
        'quantity' => $quantity,
    ), 200);
```

order.complete service:

public function returnOrder(Book $bookEntity, $userId)
    {
        $dq = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder('o')
            ->update('BaseBundle:Order', 'o')
            ->set('o.status', ':status')
            ->where('o.book = :id')
            ->andWhere('o.user = :user')
            ->andWhere('o.status = \'active\'')
            ->setParameter('status', 'done')
            ->setParameter('id', $bookEntity)
            ->setParameter('user', $userId)
            ->setFirstResult(0)
            ->setMaxResults(1)
            ->getQuery();

```
    $dq->execute();

    $this->entityManager->getRepository('BooksBundle:Book')->updateQuantityPos($bookEntity);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a http caching issue.  What does the network tab under the F12 key tell you?

Comment: You may also try to debug your controller using the [VarDumper component](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-vardumper-component). In order to do that you need Symfony 2.7 at least (the 2.6 had a bug and not showing the dump in the profiler).